# Unicode printing wrong characters

Tags: python, unicode

Unfortunately still using Python 2.7 and moving to Python 3 currently is not in the roadmap.
I am making a REST call to an external application to retrieve data which I need to then process, push into a CSV file and post that across another different REST interface.
The characters causing me problems I have receive from the first rest call are

```
u'\xe7\x83\xad\xe7\x82\xb9\xe8\xae\xa8\xe8\xae\xba'
```

which when printed are

```
>>> print u'\xe7\x83\xad\xe7\x82\xb9\xe8\xae\xa8\xe8\xae\xba'
çƒ­ç‚¹è®¨è®º
```

What this should actually be is 热点讨论

Now this data is taken and then processed without change but is written into the csv file as 'çƒ­ç‚¹è®¨è®º' and then posted to the second REST interface

The actual characters I should be receiving from the CSV file should be
热点讨论

which in unicode should look like u'\u70ed\u70b9\u8ba8\u8bba'

```
>>> print u'\u70ed\u70b9\u8ba8\u8bba'
热点讨论
```

How do I either:

1. transform the initially received unicode u'\xe7\x83\xad\xe7\x82\xb9\xe8\xae\xa8\xe8\xae\xba' into u'\u70ed\u70b9\u8ba8\u8bba' before pushing into the CSV file and posting to the second rest api
2. Cause u'\xe7\x83\xad\xe7\x82\xb9\xe8\xae\xa8\xe8\xae\xba' to print 热点讨论 correctly once on the receive side of the second REST api?

Edit: for the first REST call.
The call is being made using requests.get()
This is the response data:

```
[
{"flags":1074200578,"results":{"id1":22212362104,"id2":22212362125,"fields":[{"id1":0,"id2":0,"count":0,"format":128,"type":"ip.src","flags":0,"group":0,"value":"172.18.16.74"},{"id1":0,"id2":0,"count":0,"format":65,"type":"filename","flags":0,"group":0,"value":"WinVNC6"},{"id1":0,"id2":0,"count":0,"format":65,"type":"checksum","flags":0,"group":0,"value":"5b52bc196bfc207d43eedfe585df96fcfabbdead087ff79fcdcdd4d08c7806db"},{"id1":22212362104,"id2":22212362104,"count":0,"format":32,"type":"time","flags":0,"group":0,"value":1618530308},{"id1":22212362106,"id2":22212362106,"count":0,"format":128,"type":"device.ip","flags":0,"group":0,"value":"172.18.21.197"},{"id1":22212362108,"id2":22212362108,"count":0,"format":65,"type":"device.type","flags":0,"group":0,"value":"symantecav"},{"id1":22212362111,"id2":22212362111,"count":0,"format":65,"type":"host.src","flags":0,"group":0,"value":"\u00E7\u0083\u00AD\u00E7\u0082\u00B9\u00E8\u00AE\u00A8\u00E8\u00AE\u00BA"},{"id1":22212362114,"id2":22212362114,"count":0,"format":65,"type":"checksum","flags":0,"group":0,"value":"5b52bc196bfc207d43eedfe585df96fcfabbdead087ff79fcdcdd4d08c7806db"},{"id1":22212362117,"id2":22212362117,"count":0,"format":65,"type":"filename","flags":0,"group":0,"value":"WinVNC6"},{"id1":22212362119,"id2":22212362119,"count":0,"format":65,"type":"action","flags":0,"group":0,"value":"Left alone"},{"id1":22212362124,"id2":22212362124,"count":0,"format":65,"type":"user.dst","flags":0,"group":0,"value":"Adam_Joe"},{"id1":22212362125,"id2":22212362125,"count":0,"format":128,"type":"ip.src","flags":0,"group":0,"value":"172.18.16.74"},{"id1":22212362104,"id2":22212362104,"count":1,"format":8,"type":"time","flags":2,"group":0,"value":"1"}]}},
{"flags":1074200577,"results":{"id1":22212362126,"id2":22212362136,"fields":[]}}
]
```

The piece in this causing the issues is "\u00E7\u0083\u00AD\u00E7\u0082\u00B9\u00E8\u00AE\u00A8\u00E8\u00AE\u00BA"

Comment: Please try to clarify the flow and narrow down the problem. (1) You say that when receiving the data in the 1s REST call, already it is not encoded properly. So what is the relevance of the rest of the problem? Can we narrow it down and just focus on the 1st REST call? (2) How are you making that call and in what way response data is encoded? e.g. is it JSON and if so what is the RAW JSON string you are receiving? REST doesn't necessarily imply a method of data serialization.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have a Python *string* with that content. Having a *binary* sequence of that would work fine: `b'\xe7\x83\xad\xe7\x82\xb9\xe8\xae\xa8\xe8\xae\xba'.decode('utf-8')` gives the expected result. How did you end up with `u'\x...'` exactly?

Comment: This is the string returned from the application over the REST interface. Exactly as you see it.

Comment: about `print` and expectation of `print`: you tell the terminal to print such *bytes*, the terminal should be able to interpret it (depending the encoding/code-page) the terminal is using. So check terminal settings. Do not assume that terminals/consoles in Windows understand UTF-8

Comment: OS is centos7 not Windows.

Comment: Looks like the garbling happens on the server side. You may be able to reverse it with `.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')`.